# How to bring focus on an option in multiple select box

Tags: javascript, css, focus

I want to bring focus on an option in multiple select box. I just want the dotted border line [(click here to refer image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJFeO.png) on one of the options in a multiple select box and don't want the option to be fully selected.

I tried something like document.getElementById("multiple_dropdown").options[2].focus(); but didn't work.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use jQuery or only pure Javascript?

Comment: no image is attached?

Comment: Added the link to the image now, sorry about that.

Comment: I can use jquery too.

Answer (score 1):

After more investigation, I found that its not worth the time to try to change the default behaviour of different browsers as to how they focus on the options in the multiple select box, reason being there are not much options the browsers provide to access the <option>s in the multiple dropdowns.

```
Browser | What happens on focus of multiple dropdown after reset ?                     | Is there provision to style/focus a particular option in multiple dropdown ?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FF      | Dotted outline border on the very first option in the multiple dropdown      | We can’t set focus on a particular option, but will be able to style particular option like a dotted blue border or background etc.
IE      | Dotted outline border on the lastly selected option in the multiple dropdown | Doesn’t provide way to style/focus particular option in a multiple dropdown
Chrome  | No dotted outline on the option but a Solid thick blue border on the whole multiple dropdown itself | Doesn’t provide way to style/focus particular option in a multiple dropdown
Mac     | Same as chrome (as both are webkit family)                                   | Doesn’t provide way to style/focus particular option in a multiple dropdown
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not all browsers support `border` css property of `option` element. AFAIK Firefox does, but that's the only one. So you can't just make a border to it.
If you want to select some option, you can use JQuery's

```
$($("#multiple_dropdown").children()[2])
```

This will give you access to 3rd (because option count starts from zero) `option` element of a `<select id="multiple_dropdown">` element. If you want to somehow pick it out, I can offer you use `background-color`, for example:

```
$($("#multiple_dropdown").children()[2]).css('background-color', 'blue')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I could try using something like :  
$($("#multiple_dropdown").children()[2]).css('border', '1px dotted blue')